# Unable to bring in PieChart with the prop values from another component in ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, pie-chart, recharts

I have been trying to fetch a Pie Chart from a component's values, where in the parent component I will select element from a dropdown and along with that a table will get displayed and a pie chart as well , showing percentage of location. For eg. if aircraft D-1569 has two L1, two L2 and one L4, it should show L1 40%, L2 40% and L4 20%.

Below are two jsx components where Devdropdown is parent and Charts is child.

Devdropdown.jsx :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import Tables from "./Tables";
import Charts from "./Charts";

const Devdropdown = () => {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([{}]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  const url = "http://localhost:3000/devices";

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getDevices() {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const body = await response.json();
      setDevices(body.data);
    }
    getDevices();
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };

  const deviceMap = useMemo(() => {
    const grouped = new Map();
    for (const device of devices) {
      const currDeviceArr = grouped.get(device.device_id) ?? [];
      currDeviceArr.push(device); // add the current device to the associated device_id array
      grouped.set(device.device_id, currDeviceArr);
    }
    return grouped;
  }, [devices]);

  console.log(devices);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <h1>Aircraft {selected}</h1>
        <select
          value={selected}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="select an option"
        >
          {devices
            ? Array.from(deviceMap.keys(), (device_id) => (
                <option key={device_id} value={device_id}>
                  {device_id}
                </option>
              ))
            : null}
        </select>
         <Tables data={deviceMap.get(selected)} key={deviceMap.get(selected)} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Charts data={deviceMap.get(selected)} />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Devdropdown;
```

Charts.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { PieChart, Pie, ResponsiveContainer } from "recharts";

const Charts = ({ data = [] }) => {
  const arr = data.map((device, i) => {
    return device.location;
  });
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
      <PieChart width={400} height={400}>
        <Pie
          dataKey="value"
          isAnimationActive={false}
          data={arr}
          cx={200}
           cy={200}
          outerRadius={80}
          fill="8884d8"
          label
        />
      </PieChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

export default Charts;
```

Could you please help me in getting the pie chart?

Thanks